# Why use TBYTE vs TCHAR?

Tags: c++, unicode, byte

I'm going through some legacy code for Unicode conversion and I've seen reference to a type called `TBYTE`.

`TBYTE`, like `TCHAR` is 1 byte for an ASCII build and 2 bytes for a Unicode build.  The difference that I can see is that `TCHAR` is signed and `TBYTE` is unsigned.  These are defined in `winnt.h`.

What I don't understand is why would anyone want to define a `TBYTE` since this isn't a byte, but varies based on if the application is Unicode or not.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: I never heard of anyone using TBYTE, as you say... it makes no sense

Comment: Microsoft has to live with every mistake once made, removing declarations that were once published in an SDK version is very difficult.  Windows is very old, old enough to be around when the *char* type was still unsigned in C and C++ compiler implementations.  TBYTE isn't actually used anywhere in current versions of the SDK, I strongly recommend that you don't either.  Including TCHAR, that stopped making sense 10 years ago when the Windows 9x branch stopped being relevant.

Comment: @HansPassant: I can understand not using `TBYTE`, but why not use `TCHAR`?  As I am migrating an application to Unicode, I don't see any path other than using the `T` and `_T` types and functions.

Comment: Why on Earth would you ever consider migrating back?  The ANSI code page disaster will never be relevant again.

Comment: @HansPassant How about just migrating? :p  We do have to continue developing while migration is occurring.  To think otherwise is very naive.